# AutoMapper Configuration Validation

Tags: c#, automapper

I have strange behavior of `AssertConfigurationIsValid` and `Map` using `AutoMapper 10.1.1`

Source data:

```cs
private class A
{
    public AA Field { get; set; }
}

private class AA
{
    public string InnerField { get; set; }
}

private class B
{
    public BB Field { get; set; }
}

private class BB
{
    public string InnerField { get; set; }
}
```

Test method, that will be executed successfully:

```cs
public void Test()
{
    var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<A, B>();
    });
    var mapper = new Mapper(mapperConfig);
    var a = new A();

    mapper.Map<B>(a);
}
```

But if i add call `mapperConfig.AssertConfigurationIsValid()` before mapping it is will throw exception

```
AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException : The following member on AutoMapperTestsSO+B cannot be map...

AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException : The following member on AutoMapperTestsSO+B cannot be mapped: 
    Field 
Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the destination type AutoMapperTestsSO+B.
```

**UPD:**

Main question: it is not clear to me why calling `Map` without first calling `AssertConfigurationIsValid` works and does not throw an exception. This would be a logical behavior if `AssertConfigurationIsValid` and `Map` performed the same checks with the same mapping configuration and returned the same result

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Nested-mappings.html

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu, okay, i am understood that call to Map does not need to specify any inner type mappings, only the type map to use for the source value passed in, but why AssertConfigurationIsValid() throws exception in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

As the docs say, you're missing the map for the inner types.

```
CreateMap<AA, BB>();
```

Comment: It is worth clarifying my question. It is not clear to me why calling Map without first calling AssertConfigurationIsValid works and does not throw an exception. This would be a logical behavior if AssertConfigurationIsValid and Map performed the same checks with the same mapping configuration and returned the same result

Comment: `Map` doesn't validate anything. It throws when it has to.

Comment: Note that your `Map` call only succeeds because `Field` is `null`. Set it to some value and `Map` will throw. `null` maps trivially to `null` by default.